# Are L. arvix and L. aries cognates?

Tags: etymology, latin

[***arvix***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arvix#Etymology)

> sacrificial ram

[***aries***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aries#Etymology)

> From a Proto-Indo-European root meaning "jump, spring," cognate with Old High German irah (“ram”), Old Irish heirp (“kid”), Ancient Greek ἔριφος, Armienian արոջ (“lamb”), Old Church Slavonic йарици, Lithuanian erytis and Middle High German ireh (“ram”).

I just wondering the simlarities both in meaning and spelling of them, and maybe they are cognates?

Comment: I don't know that 'cognate' is the word you're necessarily looking for - typically 'cognate' refers to two words that come from entirely the same source word. In this case, if the two words are related (and I don't know at all if they are), they might share a root, but they'd have different suffixes (which would have all fossilised together by the time of Latin).

Comment: Within the field of Indo-European linguistics (and beyond?), ‘cognate’ is often used of words (in the same language or another) that come from comparable derivations of the same root, rather than the exact same form. The latter is often referred to as an ‘exact cognate’ instead. For example, the cognates listed in the ‘aries’ quote above are all from the same root, but enlarged by at least two different suffixes: one containing a _*-bʰ-_ and one containing a _*-k-_ (or _*-ḱ-_).

Comment: Ima guess: It was just a different spelling kept up by devout scribes, the original pronounciation forgotten, *v* from /u y/, *x* from /t/ through a change in alphabet (slightly tilting the T), perhaps a loan. Otherwise, the suffix might be https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/bʰuǵ- whereas Aries is obviously contaminated with Greek *Aris* through folk etymologyy. Otherwise try \*Hreytkos assume contraction once shift from syllabary to alphabetic spelling took place.